# JSON API Plugin for wordpress not returning the right things

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, wordpress

I create a mobile application for my site in static html, now i want use ajax to take my posts, pages, titles, images, etc.. from my wordpress original site.

For this, the best solution i think is use the JSON API plugin -> https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

I already installed, and it's working good in the pages, except for the main page, it's not sending the right thinks for my mobile app.

Anyone knows what is the problem? This is a problem with my wordpress site or maybe a plugin problem?

It's sending this:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "count": 1,
  "count_total": 1,
  "pages": 1,
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1689,
      "type": "post",
      "slug": "teste",
      "url": "http://myurlsite.com/teste/",
      "status": "publish",
      "title": "Teste",
      "title_plain": "Teste",
      "content": "<p>[123-contact-form i523156]</p>\n",
      "excerpt": "<p>[123-contact-form i523156]</p>\n",
      "date": "2013-12-10 20:11:14",
      "modified": "2013-12-10 20:11:14",
      "categories": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "slug": "sem-categoria",
          "title": "Sem categoria",
          "description": "",
          "parent": 0,
          "post_count": 1
        }
      ],
      "tags": [],
      "author": {
        "id": 1,
        "slug": "admin",
        "name": "admin",
        "first_name": "Administrador",
        "last_name": "Wemaster",
        "nickname": "admin",
        "url": "",
        "description": ""
      },
      "comments": [],
      "attachments": [],
      "comment_count": 0,
      "comment_status": "open",
      "custom_fields": {
        "cro_sidebar": [
          "1"
        ],
        "cro_sidebarsel": [
          "0"
        ],
        "cro_readmore": [
          "1"
        ],
        "cro_showpromo": [
          "1"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If u observe, it's returning a post, not a page:

```
 "type": "post",
 "slug": "teste",
  "url": "http://myurlsite.com/teste/",
  "status": "publish",
  "title": "Teste",
  "title_plain": "Teste",
```

I delete the test post and now it~s returning this:

```
{"status":"ok","count":0,"count_total":0,"pages":0,"posts":[]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try accessing the post via this url:

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/api/get_page/?slug=<page-slug>
```

or use the page id instead:

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/api/get_page/?id=<page-id>
```

I've tested both and both work with that plug-in.

For more information read [this information by the developer(s)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/#1.1.-Requests).